# How to speed up this inter-array process? [Python, Numpy]

Tags: python, numpy

Having two numpy arrays([samples vs clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLWft.png)):

```
data(n_samples, n_featuers)
clusters(n_clusters, n_features)
```

Goal is to compute a numpy array of indexes of the closest clusters to each sample:

```
new_assignments(n_samples)
```

Present code is below:

```
def assign_clusters_to_samples(data, clusters, assignments):
    # clusters-array of clusters, sample-single sample from the database
    def get_index_from_euclidean_distances(clusters, sample):
        e_distances = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(clusters,sample),2), axis=1))
        # return index with the minimal distance
        return np.where(e_distances==np.min(e_distances))[0]

    new_assignments = np.empty((0,1), int)
    # iterate through all samples
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        new_assignments = np.append(new_assignments, get_index_from_euclidean_distances(clusters,data[i]))
    # return new assignments and True if there is a difference to last assignments, False otherwise
    return new_assignments, find_difference(new_assignments, assignments)
```

It is however very slow. How to make the process faster? Is there other optimal ways to solve the issue?

EDIT:

My code above is a core section of a k-means clustering algorithm which is responsible for 99.9% of the execution time. I'm building it from scratch for educational purposes and with your answers I got what I needed.(sorry for earlier editing and confusions, it is my first question, future ones will be more specific and provide all information and data needed for debugging and problem reproducibility)

Thank you [Sobek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3800761/sobek). Applying `np.apply_along_axis` improved performance from [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Porpo.png) to [apply_along_axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuEP2.png).

I will continue building a solution suggested by [Eli Korvigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846213/eli-korvigo).

Thank you very much!

Comment: In the [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html#numpy.apply_over_axes) you can find the function `apply_over_axes`, this should be preferred to looping over an array to apply a function.

Comment: @sobek `apply_along_axis` won't be far too helpful with Python functions.

Comment: @sobek pure numpy operations and/or Cython/Numba functions. `apply_over_axes` (and its siblings) can't do much more than a standard Python loop will give you, if you call pure Python functions.

Comment: Could you post a small sample of data? This operation could probably be completely vectorized.

Comment: **"And for unknown reasons ran into a Memory bound error."** – can you provide a minimal reproducible example, containing your function definition, data generation, function call and the error message with stack trace? **"Currently the performance compared to scikit's solution"** – what "scikit's solution" you are referring to? If that is something along the lines of my answer (i.e. a search tree), then you won't be able to beat it with your naïve solution regardless of any possible optimisations (including vectorisation), due to fundamental time-complexity (I've explained it in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Let's assume, you have a set of `C` centroid points (`clusters`) in an N-dimensional vector space with a Euclidean metric and a set of `Q` query points (`samples`) in the same space. Now, if you want to find the closest centroid for each query point, you can use a search tree (e.g. a [K-D tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)) to do this in approximately `O(QlogC)`, whereas your current approach is `O(Q**2)`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric, KDTree

In [3]: clusters = np.array([
   ...:     [0, 1],
   ...:     [10, 5]
   ...: ])

In [4]: tree = KDTree(clusters, metric=DistanceMetric.get_metric('euclidean'))

In [5]: samples = np.array([
    ...:     [0, 2],
    ...:     [10, 6]
    ...: ])

In [6]: tree.query(samples, return_distance=False)
Out[6]: 
array([[0],
       [1]])
```

**Original answer (including the post scriptum)**

I see `np.append` calls inside a loop, which are generally considered a red flag for poorly optimised code, because NumPy arrays are not dynamic: `np.append` has to reallocate and copy its operands at each iterations. You'll be far better off accumulating arrays in a list and calling `np.concatenate` on the resulting list.

```
def assign_clusters_to_samples(data, clusters, assignments):
    # clusters-array of clusters, sample-single sample from the database
    def euclidean_distances(clusters, sample):
        e_distances = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(clusters,sample),2), axis=1))
        # return index with the minimal distance
        return np.where(e_distances==np.min(e_distances))[0]

    # iterate through all samples
    acc = [euclidean_distances(clusters, data[i]).flatten() for i in range(data.shape[0])]
    new_assignments = np.concatenate(acc)
    # return new assignments and True if there is a difference to last assignments, False otherwise
    return new_assignments, find_difference(new_assignments, assignments)
```

P.S.

1. I'm not sure you are calling `np.append` without specifying `axis` intentionally (after all, your original `new_assignments` object is explicitly non-flat): your function (and, by extension, my solution) flattens return values from `euclidean_distances` before appending/concatenating.
2. Your algorithm is not particularly efficient. Any distance-search tree data-structure would dramatically improve time-complexity.
3. Design-wise, I don't think you should call `find_difference` inside this function. Here is a cleaner (from my point of view) solution:

   ```
   def assign_clusters_to_samples(data, clusters):
       # clusters-array of clusters, sample-single sample from the database
       def euclidean_distances(clusters, sample):
           distances = np.sum((clusters - sample)**2, axis=1)
           # return index with the minimal distance
           return np.where(distances==np.min(distances))[0]

       return [euclidean_distances(clusters, sample) for sample in data]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard, to read euclidean_distances, because you don't use mathematical operators but numpy methods.
Using numpy.append is very slow, because each time the whole array has to be copied.

```
def assign_clusters_to_samples(data, clusters, assignments):
    # clusters-array of clusters, sample-single sample from the database
    def euclidean_distances(clusters, sample):
        e_distances = np.sum((clusters - sample)**2, axis=1)
        # return index with the minimal distance
        return np.argmin(e_distances)

    new_assignments = [
        euclidean_distances(clusters,d)
        for d in data
    ]
    # return new assignments and True if there is a difference to last assignments, False otherwise
    return new_assignments, find_difference(new_assignments, assignments)
```